# Android: Better way to use AsyncTask to make repeated Ajax Calls

Tags: android, ajax, timer, android-asynctask, timertask

I need my Android app to periodically fetch data from a server using AJAX calls, and update the UI accordingly (just a bunch of TextViews that need to be updated with setText()).

Note that this involves 2 tasks:

-Making an AJAX call, and updating the UI once I receive a response - I use a simple AsyncTask for this.

-Doing the above repeatedly, at regular intervals.

**I am not sure which of below two methods  for repeated calling of AsyncTask I should prefer for better performance.**

**Method 1:** Calling the execute() repeatedly from inside of **onCreate** method but the problem I think with this method would be before completion of one AsyncTask request, another AsynTask request might come (if processing time of request is more than schedular delay time )and there might be possiblity of many request in a queue which can ultimately harm the performance.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_list_view);

    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new AjaxRequestTask().execute();  // Async Call
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 2000); //execute in every 2000 ms
}
```

**Method 2:** Calling the execute() repeatedly from inside of **onPostExecute** but the problem I think with this method would be recursion and in every call new object of AjaxRequestTask will be created before the older one get destroyed and there will be situation when lot of AsynTask object will be present in memory which can ultimately harm the performance.

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

   final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        new AjaxRequestTask.execute();  // Async Call
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 2000);


 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`AsyncTask.execute` runs sequentially i.e whenever you will use `AsyncTask.execute` your worker thread will add in queue, it means you have to wait for the completion of previously added task (FIFO).
Use `AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR, params)` this will create a parallel `AsyncTask` and you don't have to wait.

In your case you can create a [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) or [`ExecutorService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) to limit the number of your `AsyncTask` or `Runnable`.

You can do this by creating a pool executor

```
ExecutorService  yourCustomPoolExector = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5); // 5  is max number of tasks 
AjaxRequestTask.executeOnExecutor(yourCustomPoolExector, params);
```

At any time you can cancel your all `AjaxRequestTask`'s by calling[`yourCustomPoolExector.shutdownNow`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdownNow()).

If you want to perform your desired functionality at regular intervals you may consider [`Sync Adapter`](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html) (but i don't think you need to use this).

Answer (score 0):

For repeating task you and making requests in background RxJava library is a better solution. With RxJava 1 it will look like:

```
Subscription repeatingTask =
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.map(t -> {
// make your request here, it is done on background thread already
Response r = makeRequest();
return r;
})
// process result on a main thread
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe (r -> {
processResponse(r);
}, 
e -> {
processError(e);
};
```

Cancel that task when you need it no longer

```
if (null != repeatingTask && !repeatingTask.isUnsubscribed()) {    repeatingTask.unsubscribe();    repeatingTask = null; {
```